# Trouble calling DLL function

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have bought a printer device which was provided with a DLL enclosing the functionality and require to call the C++ functions inside that DLL from my C# code. However, I am always getting an error when I try to do so. Also using the same code provided with the application works fine. Following is some part of my code:

```
[DllImport("Msprintsdk.dll", EntryPoint = "SetInit", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern unsafe int SetInit();
```

And calling the above function like:

```
var res = SetPrintport(new StringBuilder("USB001"),0);

if (res == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printer Setup Successful.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printer Setup Un-Successful.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: make sure that all the C++ libs and dlls are in the bin folder.

Comment: Have you placed the DLL inside your bin/Debug folder or not? If not do place it there.

Comment: Are you trying to call a 32 bit DLL from a 64 bit EXE (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 1):

All possible issues you might face when working with C++ dll are listed as follows:

First of all do make sure you are placing the DLL in your \bin\Debug folder.

Next determine if the DLL is x86 or x64. In case of x86 DLL you need to check mark the Prefer 32-bit option in VS.

What it will look like:
[image]

How it should be like (notice the Prefer 32-bit checked now):

[image]

Last but not the least you have to check the .NET framework your are using.
If using .NET 3.5 your code should look something like:

```
[DllImport("Msprintsdk.dll", EntryPoint = "SetInit", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern unsafe int SetInit();

var res = SetPrintport(new StringBuilder("USB001"),0);

if (res == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printer Setup Successful.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printer Setup Un-Successful.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

If using .NET 4 or higher your code should look like:

```
[DllImport("Msprintsdk.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SetInit", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern unsafe int SetInit();

var res = SetPrintport(new StringBuilder("USB001"),0);

if (res == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printer Setup Successful.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Printer Setup Un-Successful.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Notice the added  `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

These are the most common problems in my opinion anyone will come across when starting to work with C++ dlls.

Using your provided code to demonstrate the example as I am too lazy to write my own :).
Hope this might help your case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this declaration?

```
[DllImport("Msprintsdk.dll", EntryPoint = "SetPrintport", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern unsafe int SetPrintport(StringBuilder strPort, int iBaudrate);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."